# Problems Deleting Descriptors in Apache Nifi Using Rest API

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use the rest API to dynamically update and control my Apache NiFi Flow. I am using Postman to explore the REST API but am having trouble deleting properties/descriptors.

My current process is to call a GET to this address - http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/processors/{ID}

I then modify the response as desired and do a PUT with the modified response as the body. If I add a descriptor or change the content of a descriptor it works ok. But if I try to delete a descriptor by removing it from the properties and descriptors area then nothing happens.

I still get a 200 OK response, but it is the same as the original.

I am using NiFi 1.1.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PropertyDescriptors are specified by the Processor in question. These are read-only values and describe the properties the Processor currently supports. In you want to remove a property, and it is optional, you should be able to remove the value for it by setting it's entry to null in properties object in your request.